# Flutter: How do I build a list outside of a widget's build function if I need to use variables from a provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have a function called `getFormsList` in my Database class that does some asynchronous work and returns a list. I need to display this list in my Forms widget (see below). The tricky part is that `getFormsList` requires some parameters that are variables from `GlobalsProvider`, which is just a provider that holds global variables.

From my research online, I see that I should not be calling the function inside the widget's `build` function because this function could be called every frame and that would be doing too much work. So, it's better to get your list outside of `build`, such as in `initState` or something.

Below is what I tried, but I don't know how to use the global variables from `GlobalsProvider` in my `initialize` function.

```
class _FormsState extends State<Forms> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> formsList = [];
  final db = Database();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); //Run this first
    initialize();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    formsList = db.getFormsList(parm1: globals.var1, parm2: globals.var2); //This doesn't work because I don't have access to the global variables here
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, globals, child) => Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: // ???,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) async {
              // ???
            }
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```